# Property 'X' does not exist on type 'FastifyContext<unknown>'

Tags: typescript, namespaces, fastify

I want to add the `token: string` field to the FastifyContext interface. For this purpose I have created the following file structure:

```
projectDir
|__src
|  |__@types
|  |  |__fastify
|  |  |  |__index.d.ts
|  |__api
|  |  |__authHook.ts
|__tsconfig.json
```

Content of `src/@types/fatify/index.d.ts`:

```
declare module 'fastify' {
    export interface FastifyContext<ContextConfig>{
        token: string
    }
}
```

Content of `src/api/authHook.ts`

```
import {FastifyRequest, FastifyReply} from "fastify";


export default async function authHook(request: FastifyRequest, reply: FastifyReply): Promise<void>{
    // Some logic 
    const token = "example_token" // some result from logic 
    request.context.token = token;
}
```

Content of `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
     ...
     "typeRoots": ["src/@types"],
     ...
  }
}
```

But when I run the code I get the following error:

```
Property 'token' does not exist on type 'FastifyContext<unknown>'.
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import { onRequestHookHandler } from "fastify";

declare module "fastify" {
  export interface FastifyRequestContext {
    token: string;
  }
}

const authHook: onRequestHookHandler = async function (request, reply) {
  const token = "example_token";
  request.context.token = token;
};

export default authHook;
```

Comment: It's working. But I want to store all external library typing in a separate directory. Can I do that?

Comment: yes. don't change typeRoots. simply put your d.ts file in any directory inside src